# How to make navbar on all pages?

Tags: navbar

would i use php include? And in order to do so do my files have to be uploaded to a web host? since it is a server side language?

I have tried php include before but it does not work(below is the navbar.php 
file)

```
enter code here
```

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="aboutme.html">About me</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="contactme.html">Contact me</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

ANYTHING will help

thanks

```
enter code here
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>< ?php include 'aboutme.php'; ?></head>
<body>get it now</body>
< ?php include 'aboutme.php';
```

Comment: Please add existing code.

Comment: There are lots of ways to solve this problem. Without specifying the requirements on the solution it is very hard to give advice. If you are willing to settle with php includes, then you will need a webserver serving it, php, and properly configure these to work together. If all you need is a static navabar for all your site, you could have a look at some static site generators, like: Sculpin written in  PHP. Then after generation you can use the site locally.